# Latex keep placing figure at the end of the document

Tags: wrapfigure

I guess I will just go mad till I finish my thesis... I have to make my thesis in LaTex. I never used it before so I am really struggling and having really bad time trying to solve issues. I hoped it will be lot easier than word, but it turns out that it is way more frustrating because of my poor knowledge. I already tried and searched on google and this forum as well, and I found solutions, but pasting them in the editor did not at all solve my problem and I have no clue at all why...So I am desperately posting here to get some help as I am on the verge of going insane. 
So what I would like to do is to have a figure inserted on the first page and have the text wrapped around it. Therefore I used the wrapfigure package. Whatever I do the picture is put on the last page by Latex and I really do not understand why.

Here is my code:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}




\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext} % kamuszoveget ad
\usepackage{hyperref} % ez csinal linket a contentsbol
\usepackage{geometry} % ez a margin beallitasokat
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %ez az oldalszamozast csinalja
\usepackage{mathptmx} % ez a times new roman
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e} %justification left/right
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
%\pagenumbering{arabic}


\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}


\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\huge}{\large}{\center}{}% for \chapter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\Huge}{\large}{\center}{}% for \chapter
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\Huge}{\large}{\center}{}% for \chapter*
\makeatother

\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}




\geometry{a4paper, left=35mm, right=20mm, top=40mm, bottom=40mm}



\title{Diplomamunka}
\date{}
\author{Zsarnowszky Loránt}



\begin{document}


\maketitle
\newpage


\tableofcontents

\newpage
\justify




\section{Bevezetés}
%ez itt egy komment
Alapvetően három különböző típusú robotot különböztetünk meg: a vezérelt robot, az automatizált robot és az autonóm azaz önálló robot. A vezérelt robotok esetében mindenképp szükség van emberi üzemeltetésre. Ezek jellemzően olyan robotok melyek teljes mértékben függnek az emberi irányítástól, önállóan semmilyen feladatot, tevékenységet nem végeznek. Vezérelt robotokat gyakran alkalmaznak orvosi műtétek során illetve katonai akciók, bombák hatástalanítása alkalmából. Az automatizált robotok eklatáns példai az ipari robotok. Ezek olyan robotok melyek egy előre beprogramozott műveletsort végeznek el egy ellenőrzött környezetben ismétlődő ciklusokban. Ilyen robotokat gyakran láthatunk gépjármű-összeszere-lő üzemekben vagy akár általunk összerakott és leprogramozott Lego Mindstorm robot is ezen robotcsoportba sorolható. Az előző két típussal ellentétben az autonóm  (vagy önálló) robotok képesek egy - akár - számukra ismeretlen környezetben saját döntéseket hozni a megadott cél elérése érdekében. Egyre több ilyen robottal találkozhatunk a jelenkorban: az önjáró fűnyíróktól, az önvezető autókon keresztül egészen a csomagszállító drónokig. Napjaink egyik legnagyobb kihívása, hogy minél több - ember által elvégzett - feladatot átadhassunk a robotoknak, úgy, hogy a szükséges emberi beavatkozást minimálisra csökkent-sük. 
Az autonóm robotok lehetőséget adnak arra, hogy óriási mértében növeljük a termelés minőségét és hatékonyságát. Csak, hogy megemlítsek egy pár ilyen területet a teljesség igénye nélkül: csomagszállítás, logisztika, takarítás, mezőgazdaság, földművelés.

%\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\textwidth}
%\centering
%\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{kiva_robot.png}
%\caption{\label{fig:frog1}This is a figure caption.}
%\end{wrapfigure}


\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{kiva_robot.png}
\caption{\label{fig:frog1}This is a figure caption.}
\end{wrapfigure}










Ahhoz, hogy egy nap majd ezen tevékenységeket robotok végezhessék nagyon fontos, hogy balesetmentesen és megbízhatóan tudjanak közlekedni számukra ismeretlen, még fel nem térképezett területeken is. Ezen szakdolgozat célja, hogy hozzájáruljon ezen cél elérésé-hez, azáltal, hogy megoldást javasol pár ismert problémára.   



\newpage
\section{Robot típusa - meghajtás}
%itt majd irok a differenciál meghajtásrol, a szükséges adatokról: kerék átmérő stb
\blindtext

\section{A robot vezérlése}
%itt irok a PID vezérlésről

\subsection{P vezérlés}
\blindtext
\subsection{I vezérlés}
\blindtext
\subsection{D vezérlés}
\blindtext
\subsection{PID vezérlés}
\blindtext



\newpage
\section{A robot szenzorai}
\subsection{Belső szenzorok}
\blindtext
\subsection{Külső szenzorok}
\blindtext

\newpage
\section*{Egyéb}
\blindtext


\end{document}
```

And this is what I would get:
[image]

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: remove `\justify`

Comment: please use `example-image` or similar for your test file, so people can run it.

Comment: similarly you should never use `\center`  they should be `\centering`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\clearpage` rather than `\newpage` to stop the figure floating too far but also for wrapfigure you need to ensure there is enough text to wrap it. finally `\center` is the internal form of `\begin{center}`  (and similarly `\justify`) these are display constructs and implemented as lists, which do not work with `wrapfig` You should almost never need to specify justification as that is the default.

here I just added duplicated one of your paragraphs, but other re-writings would be possible (or even something invisible like `\mbox{}`)

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}




\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext} % kamuszoveget ad
\usepackage{hyperref} % ez csinal linket a contentsbol
\usepackage{geometry} % ez a margin beallitasokat
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %ez az oldalszamozast csinalja
\usepackage{mathptmx} % ez a times new roman
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{ragged2e} %justification left/right
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
%\pagenumbering{arabic}


\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}


\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\huge}{\large}{\centering}{}% for \chapter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\Huge}{\large}{\centering}{}% for \chapter
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\Huge}{\large}{\centering}{}% for \chapter*
\makeatother

\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}




\geometry{a4paper, left=35mm, right=20mm, top=40mm, bottom=40mm}



\title{Diplomamunka}
\date{}
\author{Zsarnowszky Loránt}



\begin{document}


\maketitle
\newpage


\tableofcontents

\newpage
%\justify




\section{Bevezetés}
%ez itt egy komment
Alapvetően három különböző típusú robotot különböztetünk meg: a vezérelt robot, az automatizált robot és az autonóm azaz önálló robot. A vezérelt robotok esetében mindenképp szükség van emberi üzemeltetésre. Ezek jellemzően olyan robotok melyek teljes mértékben függnek az emberi irányítástól, önállóan semmilyen feladatot, tevékenységet nem végeznek. Vezérelt robotokat gyakran alkalmaznak orvosi műtétek során illetve katonai akciók, bombák hatástalanítása alkalmából. Az automatizált robotok eklatáns példai az ipari robotok. Ezek olyan robotok melyek egy előre beprogramozott műveletsort végeznek el egy ellenőrzött környezetben ismétlődő ciklusokban. Ilyen robotokat gyakran láthatunk gépjármű-összeszere-lő üzemekben vagy akár általunk összerakott és leprogramozott Lego Mindstorm robot is ezen robotcsoportba sorolható. Az előző két típussal ellentétben az autonóm  (vagy önálló) robotok képesek egy - akár - számukra ismeretlen környezetben saját döntéseket hozni a megadott cél elérése érdekében. Egyre több ilyen robottal találkozhatunk a jelenkorban: az önjáró fűnyíróktól, az önvezető autókon keresztül egészen a csomagszállító drónokig. Napjaink egyik legnagyobb kihívása, hogy minél több - ember által elvégzett - feladatot átadhassunk a robotoknak, úgy, hogy a szükséges emberi beavatkozást minimálisra csökkent-sük. 
Az autonóm robotok lehetőséget adnak arra, hogy óriási mértében növeljük a termelés minőségét és hatékonyságát. Csak, hogy megemlítsek egy pár ilyen területet a teljesség igénye nélkül: csomagszállítás, logisztika, takarítás, mezőgazdaság, földművelés.

%\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\textwidth}
%\centering
%\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{kiva_robot.png}
%\caption{\label{fig:frog1}This is a figure caption.}
%\end{wrapfigure}


\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{\label{fig:frog1}This is a figure caption.}
\end{wrapfigure}




Ahhoz, hogy egy nap majd ezen tevékenységeket robotok végezhessék nagyon fontos, hogy balesetmentesen és megbízhatóan tudjanak közlekedni számukra ismeretlen, még fel nem térképezett területeken is. Ezen szakdolgozat célja, hogy hozzájáruljon ezen cél elérésé-hez, azáltal, hogy megoldást javasol pár ismert problémára.   



Ahhoz, hogy egy nap majd ezen tevékenységeket robotok végezhessék nagyon fontos, hogy balesetmentesen és megbízhatóan tudjanak közlekedni számukra ismeretlen, még fel nem térképezett területeken is. Ezen szakdolgozat célja, hogy hozzájáruljon ezen cél elérésé-hez, azáltal, hogy megoldást javasol pár ismert problémára.   



\clearpage
\section{Robot típusa - meghajtás}
%itt majd irok a differenciál meghajtásrol, a szükséges adatokról: kerék átmérő stb
a \blindtext

\section{A robot vezérlése}
%itt irok a PID vezérlésről

\subsection{P vezérlés}
\blindtext
\subsection{I vezérlés}
\blindtext
\subsection{D vezérlés}
\blindtext
\subsection{PID vezérlés}
\blindtext



\newpage
\section{A robot szenzorai}
\subsection{Belső szenzorok}
\blindtext
\subsection{Külső szenzorok}
\blindtext

\newpage
\section*{Egyéb}
\blindtext


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It finally works. Thank you very much!
However, my text in the section is not justified anymore. How to justify it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With your help i was able to add this figure to the desired place. Now another question arise (sorry for that)...

Is there any way to have the wrapped text justified to the margin of the figure. Please see the below picture:
[image]

So can the text on the right of the picture be justified to the red line (margin of the figure)?
Thank you very much for your help!